# Problem after suspend: sudo command doesn't work, wifi does not connect

Tags: wifi, suspend

On my laptop, after waking from suspend, the WiFi does not connect and does not find any. And while trying to fix the problem, I found out that `sudo` commands in the terminal would not execute either. (just executing `sudo` results in the terminal doing nothing. No password prompts, no output.)

I also had this issue with Linux Mint 19.2 and 19.3. I'd really like to know if there is a fix for this?

elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera

EDIT (more info as per comment):

Waiting 5 minutes did not work, when I went into System Settings > Network, Wireless was displaying 'Failed'. When I tried to turn it off, then turn it on, System Settings froze. `lshw -c Network` command also did not display anything beyond the following then hung

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
Network Interfaces
```

The output of `lshw -c Network` after rebooting:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 20
       serial: 5c:93:a2:9a:76:33
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.3.0-40-generic firmware=SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.123.170 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:50 memory:f7000000-f71fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 24:f5:aa:d0:9d:12
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:19 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7200000-f7200fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

running it in `sudo` mode had two different lines as following:

```
(Wireless interface)
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
(Ethernet interface)
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
```

Comment: Some wifi cards take a while to reconnect again when you wake up from suspend. Can you wait 5 minutes and see if it connects automatically?

After those 5 minutes, if it doesn't connect, go to System Settings > Network and enable the Wireless connection if it was disabled. Does it work now?

We would need more info about your wireless card, please execute `lshw -c Network`.

Comment: @Maccer I updated the post with more info.

Comment: For your Wifi Issue try [this answer](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-qca6174-freez-after-suspend/66232/12). You need to create those 2 files inside `/etc/systemd/system/`. See the commented lines of those files (the ones starting with #) to know how to enable the service.

Comment: @Maccer I don't know if I did something wrong, but the answer in above link did not work. I changed all the path to where the commands were located, and renamed the adapter id. From what I could figure out (though I'm not really a tech savvy person) from the log from 'systemctl status network-resume.service', network-resume.service did not even run after unsuspend. 
And are the services supposed to run (disable/enable wifi) when executing 'systemctl start ...'?

Comment: I've created an answer with the correct steps for your system. Check if that works. But first execute `sudo systemctl disable network-resume.service && sudo systemctl disable network-suspend.service && sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/network-suspend.service && sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/network-resume.service` to remove the previous service that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem is that the Wireless card isn't capable of waking up after suspend. We are going to create a service that disables the wireless card on suspend and then enables it again when you start the computer.

First, open a terminal window and execute the following command:

```
sudo io.elementary.code /etc/systemd/system/network-suspend.service
```

On the window that opens, paste the following code and then close the window:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/network-suspend.service
#sudo systemctl enable network-suspend.service
#sudo systemctl start network-suspend.service
#sudo systemctl status network-suspend.service
#sudo systemctl daemon-reload
[Unit]
Description=Network suspend service 
Before=sleep.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
User=root
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo -u $USER /bin/bash -lc 'nmcli networking off'
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl stop NetworkManager
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ip link set wlp1s0  down
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rmmod  ath10k_pci
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 1
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/rmmod  ath10k_core

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

Now type on terminal again:

```
sudo io.elementary.code /etc/systemd/system/network-resume.service
```

And paste the following code. Close the window.

```
#/etc/systemd/system/network-resume.service
#sudo systemctl enable network-resume.service
#sudo systemctl start network-resume.service
#sudo systemctl status network-resume.service
#sudo systemctl daemon-reload
[Unit]
Description=Network resume service
After=suspend.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
User=root
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10
ExecStart=/sbin/modprobe ath10k_pci
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 2
ExecStart=/sbin/modprobe ath10k_core
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ip link set wlp1s0 up
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl start NetworkManager
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo -u $USER /bin/bash -lc 'nmcli networking on'
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo -u $USER /bin/bash -lc 'nmcli r wifi off'
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo -u $USER /bin/bash -lc 'nmcli r wifi on'

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Lastly, execute all of this on terminal:

```
sudo systemctl enable network-resume.service && sudo systemctl start network-resume.service && sudo systemctl enable network-suspend.service && sudo systemctl start network-suspend.service && sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And done! It should work now. It shouldn't be necessary to reboot but it won't hurt anyway!.

---

[source](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-qca6174-freez-after-suspend/66232/12)

If you want to remove this service (because it didn't work or any other reason) just execute on terminal:

```
sudo systemctl disable network-resume.service && sudo systemctl disable network-suspend.service && sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/network-suspend.service && sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/network-resume.service
```

Comment: Thank you for yout help, but this only changed wlp7s0 to wlp1s0 right?
That is what I have already done, but it did not work.
Assuming that I am also meant to change the path to where the command actually resides in as found by 'whereis'. (changing /usr/bin/sleep to /bin/sleep, /usr/bin/modprobe to /sbin/modprobe, etc)

Comment: I just wrote that to make sure you had followed the correct steps. I don't know what else to do. Maybe you should file a bug to the kernel so they may decide to solve it.

As a last option you could try to upgrade your kernel to any mainline kernel from [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/). You'd need to download 4 deb files `linux-headers- XXXX_all.deb, linux-headers-XXXX-generic_XXXX_amd64.deb, linux-image-unsigned-XXXX-generic_XXXX_amd64 and linux-modules-XXXX-generic_XXXX_amd64.deb` . Then install with `sudo apt -f install ./linux*.deb `.

Answer (score 0):

This always happen. suspend bug(after a long suspend state, 1hr or more). all ubuntu based distro i've tried have this too. reboot and it all will be ok(atleast in my experience).....

Comment: It happens after 30 seconds in suspend as well.
So there is no fix for this? I'm expected to never close my laptop lid?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue (on Ubuntu) and somehow suspected to the router. After changing the router, with the same machine and the same OS, it worked without the issue.